# javascript variable in laravel collective (input index)

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.7, laravelcollective

I am using Laravel 5.7. For forms, ideally I would like to use Laravelcollective. I use the following Javascript script to generate dynamic fields. The **variable i** (javascript) is the index added to the dynamically generated fields. **I need to pass this variable onto the field input name**, but **with LaravelCollective** I cannot find a way to make it work.

**View file:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var i=1; //THIS IS MY INDEX 

        $('#add').click(function(){
          i++; //THIS IS THE VARIABLE I WANNA USE IN LARAVELCOLLECTIVE
          $('#dynamic_field').append(
            '<div class="container dyn_container_added'+i+'"id="dyn_container_added'+i+'">'+
               '<div class="form-group">'+
                  '<div class="row">'+
                     '<div class="col">'+

                      //THIS WORKS BUT MAKES MY LIFE COMPLICATED
                      //WITHOUT LARAVELCELLECTIVE
                         '<input type="{{$input_type}}" name= "{{$input_name_1}}'+i+'{{$input_name_2}}" class="{{$input_class}}" placeholder="{{$input_placeholder}}" value="{{$input_default}}>'+

                      //THIS DOES NOT WORKS
                      //LARAVELC0LLECTIVE
                         '{{Form::text ($input_name_1.'+i+'.$input_name_2, $input_default, ['class' => $input_class_l,'placeholder'=> $input_placeholder])}}'+

                       '</div>'+
                    '</div>'+
                  '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
                    );
                });
            }); 

    </script>
```

**Controller:**

```
'field' => [
     'input_type' => 'text',
     'input_name_1' => 'product[',
     'input_name_2' => '][color]',
     'input_placeholder_l' => '-color-',
     'input_default_l' => 'white',
     'input_class_l' => 'form-control color-list'
                ],
```

Comment: You can't add PHP components with javascript.  All the {{Laravel Components}} are server-side.

Comment: So, botton line, I cannot use LaravelCollective right?

Comment: Sure, but you will have to do your looping in PHP not Javascript.

Comment: Ok! I am quite not sure why and how I should "do my looping in PHP" (quite a beginner) but I'll try to figure it out. I keep that in mind, Thanks!